# Can't run the ".bin/setup", as it simply opens the file when I attempt to run it

Tags: python, bash

I am unable to run the ".bin/setup" call. When I attempt to run this within my IDE, I am resigned to my IDE asking me where I would like to open the file.

If someone has an idea to troubleshoot this issue or has found a solution, please let me know!

Comment: did you mean `./bin/setup`?

Comment: You have to provide more details or people won't be able to help you. What IDE, setup, OS, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to execute a bash script? In that case, you must open a terminal, go to the path where the script is, and then execute ./bin/setup.